# Conflicting class/function "nice_table" from packages afex & rempsyc

Tags: r, flextable, name-collision

I am trying to use the two packages `afex` (easy anovas) and `rempsyc` (easy APA formatting for tables) in my R code. Independently, both work nicely. I use `rempsyc`'s function `nice_table` to create a table in APA formatting that can be exported to Word but also seen in the RStudio Viewer, like this:

[image: nice_table function screenshot from RStudio Viewer]

Once I load `afex` though, this function from `rempsyc` doesn´t show me a table anymore and instead gives me the following output:

```r
[1] header body footer col_keys caption blanks properties 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

To reproduce this issue, here´s a basic example based on mtcars that is also used for demonstration of `rempsyc`.

```r
library(rempsyc)

nice_table(
  mtcars[1:3, ],
  title = c("Table 1", "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"),
  note = c(
    "The data was extracted from the 1974 Motor Trend US magazine.",
    "* p < .05, ** p < .01, *** p < .001"
  )
)
#this one works


library(afex)

nice_table(
  mtcars[1:3, ],
  title = c("Table 1", "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"),
  note = c(
    "The data was extracted from the 1974 Motor Trend US magazine.",
    "* p < .05, ** p < .01, *** p < .001"
  )
)
#this one gives the error above and no table is created


detach("package:afex", unload = TRUE)

nice_table(
  mtcars[1:3, ],
  title = c("Table 1", "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"),
  note = c(
    "The data was extracted from the 1974 Motor Trend US magazine.",
    "* p < .05, ** p < .01, *** p < .001"
  )
)

#still doesn´t work
```

As you can see, my first solution was to unload afex to make this work again, but the same error remains. Specifying the package (rempsyc::nice_table) also doesn´t work. The only way I can get the function "nice_table" to work again is to close R/RStudio completely and restart from the top.

I think the problem is within the `nice` function from `afex` that outputs a dataframe of the class `nice_table` (as the manual states). This somehow seems to overwrite some default method that allows the function `nice_table` to work.

I am basically just asking if anyone knows a way that these two packages might still work together in one script. Maybe I have missed something. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The use of `rempsyc::nice_table(..)` should always work, no matter the order the packages are loaded. If its behavior changes based on other packages, then that is a bug for the author/maintainer, I suggest you open a [new issue](https://github.com/rempsyc/rempsyc/issues). If you want more comments here on SO, unless we have the packages loaded we know nothing about "doesn't work anymore", please [edit] your question to include _why_ it doesn't work. Is it a warning or error? Is the output mal-formed?

Comment: Welcome to SO, lisa_s! This is a good first question! The edit for "how it fails" is about the only thing I'd imagine to improve this. Nice job!

Comment: Hi r2evans, thank you! I added a bit more clarification on what I´m trying to achieve but it is hard to describe as the function just doesn´t work anymore and R just gives me the error I had included once I load the second package. I was hoping that maybe I just missed something to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: In the development version of `rempsyc`, I have now removed the `nice_table` class completely, so you should be able to install the new version from the r-Universe without having to use `pkgload::unload` in your script. The new version will find its way to CRAN eventually.

```r
install.packages("rempsyc", repos = c(
  rempsyc = "https://rempsyc.r-universe.dev",
  CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))
```

### Old answer

I am the `rempsyc` package maintainer. Thank you for reporting this issue. I have opened an [issue within the `afex` repository](https://github.com/singmann/afex/issues/126) to find a solution to this colliding namespace. This will hopefully be resolved in a future version of `afex`.

---

In the meanwhile, I provide an explanation of this issue below, as well as a workaround using `pkgload::unload` instead of `detach`, which you can use within your script for the time being.

### Workaround

```r
data <- mtcars[1:3, ]
table <- flextable::flextable(data)
class(table) <- c("nice_table", class(table))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(afex))

print(table)
#> [1] header     body       footer     col_keys   caption    blanks     properties
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

pkgload::unload("afex")

table
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Explanation

The `afex` package has a printing method for objects of class `nice_table` (for the `afex::nice()` function), and, of course, `rempsyc::nice_table()` also produces an object of class `nice_table`.

The specific issue is that `afex:::print.nice_table()` uses `print.data.frame(x)` on the `nice_table` object, but then does not return the `flextable`, or rather, return it invisibly, with `invisible(x)` (as seen on these [code lines](https://github.com/singmann/afex/blob/1e3ee8d438795ad60129735ae09cc8458864c7dc/R/nice.R#L338-L349)).

I *think* there is nothing I can do from my side (besides giving up on the `nice_table` class) because `afex` overwrites the printing method for this class without much robustness checks to avoid this type of conflict. Hopefully we will find a solution soon.

The workaround of `pkgload::unload` works because, unlike `detach`, it detaches the whole namespace. You can just load `afex` again later in the script if you need to and repeat these steps as needed.